# ASP MVC: add html to label text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to add some `html` together with text using `@Html.LabelFor`?

For example

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, "Email", new { @class = "col-lg-4 control-label" })
```

is rendered as

```
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="UserName">Email</label>
```

but ideally I would like to have

```
<label class="col-lg-4 control-label" for="UserName">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
```

I can easily achieve this using `CSS`, but just being curious :)

Comment: you should do an helper ad hoc for this

Comment: You would need to create you own html helper extension method to generate the html.

Comment: I was hoping there is already something built in I can use. Thank you for you comments.